# How to add a glow to the object in 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine

Once I have managed to do this once in 2017.1 version and I'm struggling to do this right now. This are my settings attached to my game object which is moving in the background. The thing which I'm trying to achieve is a visible light halo around my object.

[image]

it looked like this

[image]

how it looks now

[image]

Comment: Include a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: @Draco18s I've added some photos.

Comment: I unfortunately can't tell the difference of where a light halo is missing.

Comment: @Draco18s maybe now it is better?

Comment: Yes, that is much better. I'm still not sure what's wrong (i.e. how to fix it)